# Is it possible create dynamic view with functionalities using json in andorid

Tags: android, json, xml, rest, android-studio

like we recive a json reponce from rest API and need to create view from json at run time dynamically from java. And also discribe their functionalities like editText, sppiners,   radioButtons etc.

Comment: Anyone guide me is it possible??

Comment: yes it is possible

Comment: yes it is possible. But it completely depends on the JSON data that you are getting. You can create spinners and radio button and textviews to show the data.